# Compile Mongodb module statically into PHP to run it on AWS Lambda

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to compile Mongodb module statically into PHP.

I have successfully compiled PHP (without Mongodb module) using the instructions here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/

Then I compile Mongodb driver using the instructions here: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php. The module mongodb.so is generated and stored successfully in the PHP source files.

But in order to re-compile PHP to bundle the Mongodb module, I tried the following instructions http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.static.php, but I don't know which flag I need to use to compile PHP with the Mongodb module.

I have tried **--with-mongodb**, **--with-mongo**, **--enable-mongodb** and **--enable-mongo** but none of those are valid flags.

Could somebody be so kind to help me out with this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After spend lot of time on this, I finally can compile PHP with mongodb extension statically installed. I realized that the version of extension I was trying was not supported to accomplish this.

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver.git mongodb && \
    cd mongodb && \
    git checkout 1.5.3 && git submodule update --init && \
    cd ../ && mv mongodb ext/mongodb

RUN ./buildconf --force

RUN ./configure \
    ...
    --enable-mongodb \
    ...

RUN make -j 5 && make install
```

When checkout the extension to tag `1.5.3` I could add the `---enable-mongodb` flag on the `/configure` command.